# uiSelect Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, mean-stack, meanjs

Hi im trying to implent uiSelect 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

But when i add module
JS

```
angular.module('projects').controller('ProjectsCreateController', ['$scope', 'Projects', 'Notify', 'CustomersToId', 'Users', '$http', '$q', 'uiSelect',
function($scope, Projects, Notify,Customers, Users, $http, $q, uiSelect) {
```

HTML

```
                        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">
                        {{customers.name}} &lt;{{customers._id}}&gt;
                    </ui-select-match>
```

I get this error in chrome console

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: uiSelectProvider <- uiSelect
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/unpr?p0=uiSelectProvider%20%3C-%20uiSelect
    at ...lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at .../lib/angular/angular.js:3801:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (.../lib/angular/angular.js:3929:39)
    at .../lib/angular/angular.js:3806:45
    at getService (.../lib/angular/angular.js:3929:39)
    at invoke (.../lib/angular/angular.js:3956:13)
    at Object.instantiate (.../lib/angular/angular.js:3976:23)
    at .../lib/angular/angular.js:7307:28
    at .../lib/angular/angular.js:6696:34
    at forEach (.../lib/angular/angular.js:332:20) <div class="modal-content" modal-transclude="">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to inject `uiSelect` into your controller so first remove it.

```
angular.module('projects').controller('ProjectsCreateController', ['$scope', 'Projects', 'Notify', 'CustomersToId', 'Users', '$http', '$q', 
function($scope, Projects, Notify,Customers, Users, $http, $q) {
```

`ui.select` needs to be added to your module when your module is declared. You also need to include `ng-sanitize`.

```
var module = angular.module('projects', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);
```

Make sure you also include `ng-sanitize` javascript file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

This information is available in the [Getting Started documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: then i get this error in console insted

Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'uiSelect', required by directive 'uiSelectMatch', can't be found!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Is `ui-select-match` inside a `ui-select` because it needs to be?